# Use 3 arrays as function parameter in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters

i want use some arrays as function parameters.
i write this code but doesn't work.
please help me

and i have no idea about number of array

```
function func2(x,y,z)
{
    alert(x[1]);
    alert(y[1]);
    alert(z[1]);

}
function func1()
{
    a = [1,2,3]
    b = [3,4,5]
    c = [5,6,7]
    func2(a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: func2 should be func1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `func2` function is calling itself. Also, using `var` is a good idea here to avoid accidentally creating global variables:

```
function func2()
{
    var a = [1,2,3],
        b = [3,4,5],
        c = [5,6,7];
    func1(a,b,c);
}
```

---

**Update** given your updated question, if you want to create a function that accepts a variable number of parameters, you'll need to access the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object:

```
function func2()
{
    alert("There are " + arguments.length + " arguments");
}
```

The `arguments` object is can be accessed just like an array (although it is not actually an array). So to print the second element from each array (remember array indexes start at 0), you'd use something like this:

```
function func2()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        alert(arguments[i][1]);
}
```

An alternate strategy would be to just accept an array of arrays (also called a multidimensional array, though technically multidimensional arrays aren't supported in JavaScript) like this:

```
function func2(a)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        alert(a[i][1]);
}
function func1()
{
    var a = [1,2,3],
        b = [3,4,5],
        c = [5,6,7];
    func2([a,b,c]);   // notice the […] around the parameters
}
```

Comment: I wrote wrong here, i have 2 problem , I'm not sure how many array

Comment: @user3564588 Your edit invalidates both of the posted answers. **Please don't do that**. But what do you mean by "how many array"? Do you want to know how many elements are in each array? If so, use the `length` property.

Comment: no , i want use func2 in a lot of place. in 1 place it have 2 parameters and in the other place it have 10 parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
function func1(x,y,z)
{
    alert(x[1]);
    alert(y[1]);
    alert(z[1]);
}
function func2()
{
    var a = [1,2,3];
    var b = [3,4,5];
    var c = [5,6,7];
    func1(a,b,c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read you minds well, you have to use `arguments` in order to iterate over a dynamic number of arguments. Assuming you pass only arrays to `func2`:

```
function func2() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(arguments[i][1]);
    }
}
```